# Tikz Trouble recreating file

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I am having trouble recreating what is pictured. I am not sure if I need to use a minipage or a table.  I don't need the QR code. Here is what I have. I am missing the equations and would like my table centered as well as the image under the text and table as you can see in the image.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{parskip,multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[margins=.5]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=6cm}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Example 3} Find each of the following limits. 

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
       
        \item[(a).] The graph of \(f(x)\) is shown below. 
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[grid=both,axis lines=middle,
                xmin=-5,
                xmax=8,
                ymin=-5,
                ymax=5,
                xtick distance=2,
                ytick distance 2, 
                ]
                    \draw[thick,red,samples=100] (-2,0)--(2,2)--(4,-2)--(7,-2);
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \quad
        
        \item[(b).] The function \(f(x)\) and \(g(x)\) are differentiable for all \(x\) use the following table to help find the limit. 
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                    \(x|\)&\(f(x)\)&\(f^\prime(x)\)&\(g(x)\)&\(g^\prime(x)\) \\ \hline
                    2&4&-2&0&3 \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
              
     \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code gives an error.

Comment: Do you want things centred relative to the width of the text above or centred relative to the column width?

Comment: @cfr centered relative to the text above it.

Comment: To do that, you'd have to measure the text. You'd also end up with differently aligned things if you repeated the same pattern more than once in the column. And the two columns would not have any symmetry. So you could do it, but I'm not sure the results would be satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives multiple errors. I've fixed those errors, but cannot say whether I have divined your intent or not.

I would recommend not centring the image or table here. I think it results in rather odd looking results. If you centre relative to the width of the column, the result looks uncentred when the text before is shorter than the column width. But if you centred relative to the text before, centred things wouldn't be aligned relative to one another and the result would be a mess.

I'd be inclined to make the `Find ...` into captions with `\captionof` from `capt-of` or `caption`, but if they are to simply be part of the text, I'd use whatever alignment I used for the graph and table.

The following centres the image and table, together with their associated `Find ...` using a `center` environment. To ensure all of the first question stays together and that (a) and (b) are aligned at the top, we  use `\columnbreak`. I don't see what `\quad` is supposed to do if you're using `multicols`.

I've also used `enumitem` to configure the `enumerate` so we don't have to hardwire the item labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip,multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=6cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Example 3} Find each of the following limits. 

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*).]
    \item The graph of \(f(x)\) is shown below. 
    
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[grid=both,axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-5,
            xmax=8,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=5,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2, 
            ]
            \draw[thick,red,samples=100] (-2,0)--(2,2)--(4,-2)--(7,-2);
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
        Find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} \frac{f(x)}{x^2-9} $
      \end{center}
    \columnbreak
    
    \item The function \(f(x)\) and \(g(x)\) are differentiable for all \(x\) use the following table to help find the limit.
    
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          \(x|\)&\(f(x)\)&\(f^\prime(x)\)&\(g(x)\)&\(g^\prime(x)\) \\ \hline
          2&4&-2&0&3 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}  
        
        Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{f(x)-4}{g(x)\cdot x^2}$
      \end{center}      
    
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of specified changes]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You only had a few small errors, but the most serious one was that you didn't have a `\end{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{parskip,multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{stackrel}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=6cm}

\begin{document}
    
    \subsection*{Example 3} Find each of the following limits. 
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            
            \item The graph of $f(x)$ is shown below. 

$\stackrel[\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\frac{x}{x+h}]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=both,axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-5,
            xmax=8,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=5,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2, 
            ]
            \draw[thick,red,samples=100] (-2,0)--(2,2)--(4,-2)--(7,-2);
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}{}$
            \quad
            
            \item The function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$are differentiable for all $x$ use the following table to help find the limit. 
$\stackrel[\displaystyle{f(x)=\frac{x}{x+h}}]{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \(x|\)&\(f(x)\)&\(f^\prime(x)\)&\(g(x)\)&\(g^\prime(x)\) \\ \hline
    2&4&-2&0&3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}{}$
            
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the best way to add the equations underneath?

Comment: Hi, I'd use stackrel, see the code again

Comment: `stackrel`?! Why?

Comment: I use it because it keeps things centered, tell us what would you do?

Comment: You have to ping @Sigur if you want your question to be seen since you have multiple users commenting on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{parskip,multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{stackrel}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=6cm}

\begin{document}
    
    \subsection*{Example 3} Find each of the following limits. 
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            
            \item The graph of $f(x)$ is shown below. 

$\stackrel[\text{\large find }\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\frac{x}{x+h}]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=both,axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-5,
            xmax=8,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=5,
            xtick distance=2,
            ytick distance=2, 
            ]
            \draw[thick,red,samples=100] (-2,0)--(2,2)--(4,-2)--(7,-2);
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}{}$
            \quad
            
            \item The function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$are differentiable for all $x$ use the following table to help find the limit. 
$\stackrel[\text{\large find } \displaystyle{f(x)=\frac{x}{x+h}}]{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \(x|\)&\(f(x)\)&\(f^\prime(x)\)&\(g(x)\)&\(g^\prime(x)\) \\ \hline
    2&4&-2&0&3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}{}$
            
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Why two answers?